# Issue with setting up Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Virtual Box (Win 7) for Magento

Tags: magento, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, hosts

I am trying to setup Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using Virtual box (in Windows 7) to enable me to do some Magento development.

I have used the following guide found in the 'Magento, the Developers Guide' book and I have setup the following in regards to the hosts file (direct from the book):

My virtual host file on Ubunto

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento.localhost.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin magento@locahost.com
    ServerName magento.localhost.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/magento_dev/public_html
 <Directory /srv/www/magento_dev/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
 </Directory>
    ErrorLog /srv/www/magento_dev/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache2, MySQL & PHP have all been setup and configured on the Ubuntu installation, and I have downloaded the Magento source via SVN (e.g /srv/www/magento_dev/public_html)

```
We just need to set up a local mapping into our host system host file by using any of the following:
• Windows
 i. Open C:\system32\drivers\etc\hosts in notepad
 ii. Add the following line at the end of the file: 192.168.43.95 magento.localhost.com

• Unix/Linux/OSX
 i. Open /etc/hosts using nano: $ sudo nano /etc/hosts
 ii. Add the following line at the end of the file: 192.168.43.95 magento.localhost.com
```

When I load up the http://magento.localhost.com directly in the browser on my Windows machine I just get a blank screen, however if I go to the IP 192.168.43.95 directly in the browser in Ubuntu it shows me the 'It works' default page for the web server.

Anyone got any ideas of what I'm doing wrong and why I cannot access this via the magento.localhost.com URL?

// update

On my Windows 7 machine I can (using cmd) ping the 192.168.0.77 address with no problem, however pinging magento.localhost.com never works? I am guessing my hosts is setup incorrectly, any ideas?

Comment: what do you have in your hosts file in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add an entry in your windows hosts file.  That file can be found at `%SystemRoot%/system32/hosts` and an entry should look like:

```
192.168.0.77     vm
```

Don't use `localhost.com` which is an actual website, and don't overwrite the default `localhost` entry (127.0.0.1)

You then should be able to access your site using `magento.vm`

Let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: Still no joy.. I've added a pastebin that shows the hosts files which you might find useful.

http://pastebin.com/dJeyeFgE

Comment: @Zabs that pastebin shows you missing a 7 on the `vm` line

Comment: And you still can't ping `magento.vm` ?

Comment: Sweet! That seems to work now :-) I now gotta figure out why it doesn't show me the default Magento installation page (it just shows the It works page) but that is one problem chalked off thanks mate :)

Comment: @Zabs if you wrote the apache configuration and enabled the site after the last restart, you may want to reload apache with `service apache reload` on the Ubuntu terminal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49662/discussion-between-david-wilkins-and-zabs)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I usually use Ubuntu Server in VirtualBox on Windows 7, so here is how I do it.

When I install Ubuntu Server, I make sure I check the ssh, LAMP, mail and Samba options.

After the install I change the settings of the VM to have another network adapter - I use one on NAT and one on host only.
In ubuntu I edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and add a dynamic address for first adapter and a static one for the second in the class of 192.168.56.x (change x with a value from 1 to 255) after you restart the networking service you should see something like eth0 10.0.2.* and eth1 with 192.168.56.x when you run `ifconfig -a`

I set up a folder in Samba `/etc/samba/smb.conf` so I can map my `/var/www/site` folder under a new letter in Windows.
Finally I change the `system32/hosts` file from Windows to point to the static ip 192.168.56.x with the ServerName or ServerAlias from the VirtualHost config.

```
192.168.56.x magento.localhost.com
```